# Conditional distribution of $\angle X$ for $X \in \mathbb{R}^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ given that $|X| = a$

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I have a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with an overall distribution $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$.  I would like to be able to specify the conditional distribution of $\angle X$ given that $|X| = a$.  How would one do this?

---

My thought is that $[\angle X \ | \ |X| = a]$ might be specified as a ["wrapped normal" distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution).  But I have no idea how to specify the parameters.

Comment: Do yo want the distribution of $|X|$ or $X$ conditioned on $|X| = a$?

Comment: I want $X$ conditioned on $|X| = a$.  Sorry, I think perhaps the notation was a bit unclear.